# Complex Javascript and HTML question, <select> and <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, css-selectors

Let's say I have multiple select box with options that have different options. On click, I want to values to be transported to a textarea. I'll try to show them in images.

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible without jQuery as well and not really complex.

Have this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyValues(oDDL, sTargetId) {
    var arrValues = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < oDDL.options.length; i++) {
        var curOption = oDDL.options[i];
        if (curOption.selected)
            arrValues.push(curOption.value);
    }
    document.getElementById(sTargetId).value = arrValues.join("\n");
}
</script>
```

Activate it from within the `select` tag like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" onclick="CopyValues(this, 'txtData');">
```

And whenever user click the drop down the selected values will be copied to textarea with the given ID, e.g.:

```
<textarea id="txtData"></textarea>
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/UBwML/

Comment: This works extremely awesome!!! Thanks!! Though, is there any tweak that would keep the current text in the textarea and add the values of the options without deleting the current text?

Comment: @Dugi no problem.. to append instead of overwrite just add this little plus sign: `document.getElementById(sTargetId).value += arrValues.join("\n");` although can't see why you need such thing..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your textarea has an ID of "text":

(**Note:** this uses the [jQuery framework](http://www.jquery.com), which makes things a lot easier. See section further down for non-jQuery solution):

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

This will replace any text already inside the textarea though. If you want to simply add it to the end (with a space), then:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('#text').val($('#text').val() + ' ' + $(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

---

**Pure Javascript solution:**

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    textarea = document.getElementById('text');
for (var i = 0, select; select = selects[i]; i++) {
    select.selectedIndex = -1;
    select.onchange = (function (s) {
        return function () {
            textarea.value +=
                ' ' + s.options[s.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            s.selectedIndex = -1;
        };
    })(select);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gdp6p/

Comment: You should add that you are using jQuery (OP is not mentioning jQuery at all). And maybe you should also provide a non-jQuery answer.

Comment: @Dugi, sorry I was using the jQuery library. I'll update my answer with a pure javascript solution. @Felix, cheers, you were absolutely right, I didn't notice that at all.

Comment: Thank you :), extremely awesome.